# Cannot debug because IIS AppPool running as x64

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, iis

I have a problem, I can't debug the code because I don't see the managed processes where I should attach. We created a solution in a virtual machine and we added to the GIT. In another VM I checked out the code, and in the new VM I am unable to debug it.

When I try to attach to the process I see only unmanaged processes, and not managed
[image]

Normally I should see this, I see these processes in the VM where it works fine, and we created the solution.
[image]

I've tried a lot of things which I found, I checked this, this is set fine
[image]

I have also checked these settings in the AppPool
Internet Information Services->Application Pools->New Pool(name it)->General->Managed Pipeline Mode
Internet Information Services->Application Pools->New Pool(name it)->General->Enable 32-Bit Applications

These are fine also.

I checked in the Modules window, when I want to debug my dll-s are not present there

[image]

Can you please advise what could be the issue?

Comment: ASP.NET runtime is not loaded when `w3wp.exe` is launched. You have to send requests to trigger that. BTW, IIS is not IIS Express, so don't misuse the tag.